# populate drop down lists with data from mysql data-base

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, menu

I'm creating a form and it asks candidates to post info about their previous education history - here are the screenshots of the form and the code attached to them!

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/ege104.png]

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/fxuf5w.png]

Here's my javascript code:

```
<script>
function removeFields1(){
//var container1 = document.getElementById("container1");
//container1.removeChild(input);


}
    function addFields1(){
        var container = document.getElementById("container1");

        var option = document.createElement("select"); //? how do I fix this up


        //option.text = "Kiwi";
        //container.add(option);
        container.appendChild(option);//? how do I fix this up


        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Address: "));//Address form

        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.id = "instaddress";
        input.name = "instaddress";
        input.size = 20;
        input.maxlenth = 20;
        container.appendChild(input);

        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("From: "));   // which year the person started        
        var from = document.createElement("input");                 // studying in that institution
        from.type = "text";
        from.id = "from";
        from.name = "from";
        from.size = 4;
        from.maxlenth = 4;
        container.appendChild(from);

        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("To: "));     // which year the person finished 
        var to = document.createElement("input");                   // studying in that institution
        to.type = "text";
        to.id = "to";
        to.name = "to";
        to.size = 4;
        to.maxlenth = 4;
        container.appendChild(to);

        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Did You Graduate?: Yes"));    // radio buttons whether someone graduated or not          

        var grad = document.createElement("input");
        grad.type = "radio";
        grad.id = "graduate";
        grad.name = "graduate";
        grad.value = "yes"; //yes value for radio button
        container.appendChild(grad);

        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" No "));
        var grad1 = document.createElement("input");
        grad1.type = "radio";
        grad1.id = "graduate";
        grad.value = "no"; //no value for radio button
        container.appendChild(grad1);

        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Certificate: "));

        var certificate = document.createElement("input");
        certificate.type = "text";
        certificate.id = "certificate";
        certificate.name = "certificate";
        input.size = 25;
        input.maxlenth = 25;
        container.appendChild(certificate);

        var addInstitution = document.getElementById(" Add");
        var removeInstitution = document.getElementById("Remove");
     //  container.removeChild(addInstitution);

        //create and insert input/text

        //create and insert button
        addInstitution = document.createElement("a");
        addInstitution.id="Add"
        addInstitution.href="#";
        addInstitution.text="Add";
        addInstitution.onclick=function(){addFields1();};

        removeInstitution = document.createElement("a");
        removeInstitution.id="Remove"
        removeInstitution.href="#";
        removeInstitution.text=" Remove";
        container.appendChild(addInstitution);
        container.appendChild(removeInstitution);
        //removeInstitution.onclick=function(){removeFields1();};
        //
        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

    }

</script>
```

Here are the form fields as well:

```
    <body>
        <form>

            <div id="container1">
        <select name="institution" id="institution">
<option <?php if(isset($_POST['institution'])) { echo $_POST['institution']; } ?>>Select Institution</option>
<?php
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM institution ORDER BY institution asc";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['institution']==$_GET['id3'])
echo("<option selected value=$row1a[institution]>$row1a[institution]</option>");
else
echo("<option value=$row1a[institution]>$row1a[institution]</option>");
}
?>
</select>
Address: <input size="20" type="text" id="instaddress" name="instaddress" maxlength="20" size="20"> From:<input type="text" id="from" name="from" size="4" > To: <input type="text" id="to" name="to" size="4">
Did You Graduate?: Yes<input type="radio" onclick="checkRadio()" id="graduate" name="graduate" value="yes"> No
<input type="radio" onclick="checkRadio()" id="graduate" name="graduate" value="no"> Certificate: <input size="20" type="text" id="certificate" name="certificate" maxlength="25" size="25">

               <a href="#" id="Add" onclick="addFields1()">Add </a><br>
            </div>

        </form>
    </body>
```

How can I create a drop-down select menu for the Javascript section when I click `addFields1()`?

The PHP code for the drop down menu is down here below-the menu is populated with data from a MySQL database. What will be the correct

```
 <option <?php if(isset($_POST['institution'])) { echo $_POST['institution']; } ?>>Select Institution</option>
<?php
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM institution ORDER BY institution asc";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['institution']==$_GET['id3'])
echo("<option selected value=$row1a[institution]>$row1a[institution]</option>");
else
echo("<option value=$row1a[institution]>$row1a[institution]</option>");
}
?>
</select>
```

Can any of you guys help me out with fixing up the Javascript code?

Here's the snippet of code that needs to be rectified so that I can use Javascript functions to drop down the menu list every time that the "Add" link is pressed:

```
 var option = document.createElement("select"); //? how do I fix this up

 var option = document.createElement("select"); //? how do I fix this up
 //option.text = "Kiwi";
 //container.add(option);
 container.appendChild(option);//? how do I fix this up
```

Comment: You should use a templating engine, or at least self made templates...code like this is a horror to review / maintain

Answer (score 0):

i think what you want to do is:

```
var select = document.createElement("select");

var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = "Kiwi";
option.innerHTML = "Kiwi";

select.appendChild(option);
```

....but producing these long javascript functions is not a good programming style...a function *should* consist of no more than 20 to 30 lines of code...so you should consider using one of these:

http://www.sitepoint.com/10-javascript-jquery-templates-engines/

or load the whole line via ajax...

Comment: what would I do if I wanted to withdraw it from a database?

Comment: what if i wanna retrieve the values from a mysql database? how will I do it then?

Comment: the area where i changed the code is giving me a blue line on the screen...why's that?

Comment: you'll need to load your data via ajax, but i really can't make out the actual question in your post.

Comment: how would i load the data via ajax?

Comment: when i click "Add" the drop down menu doesn't show up in the next listing...why's that?

Comment: you probably forgot to add it to the container?

Comment: i just added it in the container Mr. manhatten...it messes with the output even more...now the rest of the line isn't printing!

Comment: you DID add the select tough, not the option?

Comment: container.appendChild(select);

Comment: got it bud...thnx..u want me to check up with jQuery about retrieving data from the mysql database, right?

Comment: i got it finally...can u gimme tips on how to retrieve data from the database now using AJAX?

Comment: another question now...i can't seem to be adding multiple elements to the options section...should I put them in an array or what?